# Application settings for production deployment slot in Azure App Services

Tags: c#, azure, azure-appservice, azure-deployment, azure-deployment-slots

I'm going through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/stage-deploy-app-service-deployment-slots/5-exercise-deploy-a-web-app-by-using-deployment-slots) azure exercises and have a question regarding this statement:

> From the All resources view in the Azure portal, go to the Overview page of the production slot of the web app.

I have 2 deployment slots in my newly created test app services. Creating a `training-Staging` slot is the only configuration change I did for this app settings.:

```
Name                     |  Status     |  App service plan   |  Traffic % 
_________________________________________________________________________
training   (Production)  |  Running    |  ASP-Training-a8b0  | 100  
training-Staging         |  Running    |  ASP-Training-a8b0  | 0
```

However in the `All Resources` windows, I don't see a production slot (created by default) slot, only `training-Staging`:

```
Name                                       | Type                  | Resource group    | Location      | Subscription
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Application Insights Smart Detection        Action group            Training            Global          ...
ASP-Training-a8b0                           App Service plan        Training            East US         ...
Training                                    App Service             Training            East US         ...
Training                                    Application Insights    Training            East US         ...
Staging (training/Staging)                  App Service (Slot)      training            East US         ...
```

There is no link or button to go into configuration for production slot in `Deployment slots` configuration too (but such link exists for staging slot). Where can I find the production slot resource?

Comment: The production slot is the default, so configuring the app service itself is configuring that slot. For other slots, you have to select the slot first, then configure it.

Comment: then wording in the above link is not ideal, but got it, thanks